# how to change certain categories in an R data set to NA

Tags: r, dataset, categorical-data

within one of the variables of a data set within R I have certain values that I want to change to NA for hot deck imputation. The possible values within it are: "Missing", "Inapplicable", "Refusal", "Don't Know", "Not mentioned" and "Mentioned". Not quite sure how to change all except Mentioned and Not Mentioned to NA values.

Comment: You can use `df1$col1[!df1$col1 5 %in% c("Mentioned", "Not Mentioned")] <- NA`

Comment: There's a typo in @akrun's comment, remove the `5`.

Comment: @hussain My earlier comment had a typo.  It should be `df1$col1[!df1$col1  %in% c("Mentioned", "Not Mentioned")] <- NA`